# curl GET json file: Output file has additional strings 'text' and special characters like '\'

Tags: json, curl

can maybe someone support me with a **curl** request?
I am calling the REST API of Bitbucket (v 1.0) to get a json-file via a curl transfer.
The call looks as follows:

```
curl -k -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer xyxyxyz" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "https://code.somecompany.corp/bitbucket/rest/api"/1.0/projects/<projectname>/repos/davinci-reviewer-list/browse/mapfile.json --output mapfile.json
```

The output should be exactly the same like the original content of the mapfile.json:

```
{
  "repos": [
    {
      "reponame": "account-opening-svc",
      "rev_list": "BE"
    },
    {
      "reponame": "alertmanager-config",
      "rev_list": "DEVOPS"
    },
    {
      "reponame": "antivirus-lambda",
      "rev_list": "BE"
    }
]
}
```

But when I open or cat the mapfile.json, the string 'text' and the string 'lines' has been added to every line and also special characters:

```
{
    "lines": [
        {
            "text": "{"
        },
        {
            "text": "  \"repos\": ["
        },
        {
            "text": "    {"
        },
        {
            "text": "      \"reponame\": \"account-opening-svc\","
        },
        {
            "text": "      \"rev_list\": \"BE\""
        },
        {
            "text": "    },"
        },
        {
            "text": "    {"
        },
        {
            "text": "      \"reponame\": \"alertmanager-config\","
        },
        {
            "text": "      \"rev_list\": \"DEVOPS\""
        },
        {
            "text": "    },"
        },
        {
            "text": "    {"
        },
        {
            "text": "      \"reponame\": \"antivirus-lambda\","
        },
        {
            "text": "      \"rev_list\": \"BE\""
        },
        {
            "text": "    },"
        }...
        ],
    "start": 0,
    "size": 340,
    "isLastPage": true
}
```

How can I get just the original json-content?
Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved - the url was pointing to the api of Bitbucket only but the link to the raw data is needed. In my case it looks like:

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/<projectname>/repos/reviewer-list/raw/mapfile.json?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster
```